How to reconcile the verse in Yeshaya 49:14 to the beginning of Shaar HaEmunah
BH
It says in Yishaya 49:14:

‎ וַתֹּ֥אמֶר צִיּ֖וֹן עֲזָבַ֣נִי יְהֹוָ֑ה וַאדֹנָ֖י שְׁכֵחָֽנִי

whereas in Ner Mitzvah V'Torah Or (Shaar HaEmunah) it says:

וה' שכחני

Why does R. Dov-Ber Schneuri say ה'‏ (meaning י-ה-ו-ה) instead and explain the verse as if it's the name הוי'‏ when the name used in the verse is actually א-ד-נ-י?
In the actual verse, the word שכחני is said about the name אדנ'‏ and עזבני is said about הוי'‏.
However here, in Shaar HaEmunah, he asks how can שכחה be said about the name הוי'‏ when in the verse it's only said of the name אדנ'‏?
This is the part from Shaar HaEmunah:

כתיב ותאמר ציון עזבני ה' וה' שכחני וזה פלא גדול לכאורה דאיך יתכן לומר
בחי' שכחה למעלה באלקים חיים שהוא ית' למעלה מן הזמן כהוראת שם הויה היה
הוה ויהיה כא'‏


Especially according to this maamar which explain that שכחה is specifically associated with אדנ-י and not הוי-ה.

Actually, he seems to be misquoting the verse ("כתיב ותאמר ציון עזבני ה' וה' שכחני"). If it's any consolation, Malbim also misquotes this verse that way. Malbim does the same for Tehilim 30:9. IIRC, for the latter, I once saw a footnote to the commentary, that said that a prevalent edition of the Tanach (or Tehilim), at the time, had ה'‏ twice in that verse of Tehilim. Maybe the same was true for the verse in Yishaya.

@TamirEvan for the Malbim you could just say לא דק, and he didn't bother to differentiate. The Shaar Haemunah though is a real problem. Probably was quoting verse from memory.

Is the shaar hatziun specifically basing this learning off of the name havaya? To me it sounds like he's saying that it doesn't make sense to say that hashem forgets, unrelated to name. And he proves it from the name havaya. So you could say lo dak here, like the malbim mentioned earlier in the comments

@Loani I think you're right. This maamar quotes it as אדנ-י and asks the same question.

@N.T. "for the Malbim you could just say לא דק, and he didn't bother to differentiate." It is hard to say that the Malbim לא דק, when one of the stated pillars for his commentary is to show that each word of the prophets' is exact and necessary (see in the introduction to his commentary on Isaiah), and that in multiple places he goes to lengths to differentiate between seeming synonyms.

Pesikta Rabbati 31 says: "דבר אחר 'ותאמר ציון עזבני ה' וה' שכחני' מהו ה' וה' אמרה לו אפילו שתי מדות של רחמים שכתובים בך 'ה' ה' אל רחום וחנון' (שמות ל"ד ו') עזבו אותי ושכחו אותי".
